# Cookies only seted in debugg mode

Tags: javascript, cookies

Cookies are saved locally in the normal way, but when I upload the changes to the server, the cookies are only saved if the browser's debug mode is open.
The proyect is ASP .NET Core

The cookie:
`document.cookie = 'cookie-value; SameSite=Lax; secure';`

local url: https://...

server url: http://...

Comment: You are trolling, right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies - if the server is accessed via http good luck transferring `secure` cookies.